# Store S4 object in matrix

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm trying to put a simple self-defined `S4`-object into a container like `data.frame`, `matrix` or `data.table`. When trying to assign an instance of my `Course`-class into a `matrix` like

```
slots <- matrix(NA, ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
slots[1,1] <- new(Class="Course", ATTRIBUTES GO HERE...)
```

I receive the following error:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The call `length(MYOBJECTINSTANCE)` returns 1 though.

Thats my class

```
setClass(
    Class="Course",
    representation=representation(
      tutor = "character"
      #other attributes...
      )
  )
```

I have also tried to implement a dummy `validate` method that always returns `true`, but witout effect.

```
setValidity("Course", function(object) {
  return(TRUE)
})
```

So now my question is:
**Is there a simple way to add a `S4`-object into a `matrix` or an equivalent container?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a matrix with S4 objects as elements by putting the items first into a list.

```
slots <- list(
   new(Class="Course"),
   new(Class="Course"),
   new(Class="Course"),
   new(Class="Course"))
```

Then just set the `dim` attribute accordingly to obtain a matrix:

```
dim(slots) <- c(2,2)
```

Example:

```
slots # don't bother
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] ?    ?   
## [2,] ?    ?   
slots[[1,1]] # element access
## An object of class "Course"
## Slot "tutor":
## character(0)
```

Comment: Seconds after I posted the quetion I found a functioning solution via sapply but your use of `list` in combination of setting the `dim` seems quite elegant to me. I think I will use a modified version of it :) Is there a way to override the `?`-print by implementing a `print` or `show`-method in S4?

Comment: @Zhedar: I don't think so. Looking at the [source code](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/print_8c.html) of the `print*` functions family, it seems that `"?"` is hard-coded.

Comment: Well, then I will write an additional method for that, doesn't really hurt that hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could update your code to work with

```
slots <- matrix(list(), ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
slots[[1,1]] <- new(Class="Course")
```

Note the addition of `list()` in the matrix initialization. A matrix of lists is somewhat special. So to extract the actual object at `(1,1)` you use `[[1,1]]` while `[1,1]` will be a list with the element at `(1,1)` in it.